# PHP add keys to nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, key-value

I have nested arrays that do not have keys. I want to add keys in a particular order. What is a clean way to do this?

Start with this array. It is only indexed by position.

```
[0] => (
    [0] => Tyler
    [1] => Durden
    [2] => 05/07/1985
)
[1] => (
    [0] => Edward
    [1] => Norton
    [2] => 03/21/1988
)
```

Now apply these keys in order:

```
['first_name'] =>
['last_name'] =>
['birthday'] =>
```

Final array:

```
[0] => (
   ['first_name'] => Tyler
   ['last_name'] => Durden
   ['birthday'] => 05/071985
)
[1] => (
    ['first_name'] => Edward
    ['last_name'] => Norton
    ['birthday'] => 03/21/1988
)
```

Bonus upvotes if your code allows for any key structure, instead of being hard-coded!

Comment: I tried it myself using a bunch of nested foreach loops. It was super inefficient and clear that a more elegant method must exist. I did ATTEMPT it myself, thanks. I also went through all the PHP functions but didn't realize that array_combine could work in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) will do the trick:

```
foreach ($bigarray as &$x) {
  $x = array_combine(array('first_name','last_name','birthday'),$x);
}
```

Comment: What is the ampersand in `($bigarray as &$x)` for?

Comment: The ampersand lets us loop through the array [by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) so that we can change the array values as we go.

Answer (score 0):

Also the classic algorythm:

```php
foreach ( $array as $key=>$value ) {
   $array[$key]['first_name'] = $array[$key][0];
   $array[$key]['last_name'] = $array[$key][1];
   $array[$key]['birthday'] = $array[$key][2];
   unset($array[$key][0]);
   unset($array[$key][1]);
   unset($array[$key][2]);
}
```